# Let $R \in A$ such that $|\mathbb{N}/R|=2$, Proof if $R$ has finite equivalence class so $[R]_E$ is countable

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

I have the following question :

$A \subseteq P(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}) $ group of equivalence relation above $\mathbb{N}$, let $E \subseteq A^2$ a relation that is defined in the following manner :

$(R_1,R_2)\in E$ if exists function $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ surjective and injective such all $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$, $(x,y)\in R_1$ if and only if $(f(x),f(y))\in R_2$

$E$ is a equivalence relation, let $R \in A$ such that $|\mathbb{N}/R|=2$, Proof if $R$ has finite equivalence class so $[R]_E$ is countable.

**What I did :**

I don't really know how to approach this, This is what I managed to concluded:

Since $|\mathbb{N}/R|=2$ so there is $[C]_R,[D]_R \in$ $\mathbb{N}$ $/R$ such that $N/R=\{[C]_R,[D]_R\}$ its clear that $[C]_R \neq [D]_R$ and as well that $(C,D)\not \in R$, but I don't understand  how the equivalence class of $\mathbb{N}/R$ is connected with $R/E=[R]_E$?

Any ideas/suggestions?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Oh, I think what it means if one of the equivalent classes $[C]_R,[D]_R$ is finite, then $[R]_E$ is countable.

Comment: And you shouldn't write $C,D\in\mathbb N/R$. It is $[C]_R,[D]_R\in\mathbb N/R$, for some $C,D\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you, Edited, Could you expand what you said in first comment? how did you conclude that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ has a finite equivalence class. This means there exists a finite subset $F$ of $\Bbb N$ such that for each $x,y\in\Bbb N$ hold $(x,y)\in R$ iff both $x,y$ in $F$ or both $x,y$ not in $F$. Let $(R,R’)\in E$. Then there exists a bijection $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$, $(x,y)\in R$ iff $(f(x),f(y))\in R’$. Thus  $(f(x),f(y))\in R’$ iff both $f(x),f(y)$ in $f(F)$ or both $f(x),f(y)$ not in $f(F)$. Therefore the relation $R’$ is completely determined by image of $f(F)$. Since the set $F$ is finite, there are countably many different images $f(F)$, so there are at most countably many different relations $R’$ such that $(R,R’)\in E$.